# zsh completion for sshpass

Tags: ssh, zsh, autocomplete, sshpass

I am using `sshpass` command like this:

```
sshpass -p 'my_password' ssh user@server
```

The full syntax, according to the man page is

```
sshpass [-ffilename|-dnum|-ppassword|-e] [options] command arguments
```

At the moment, zsh does not have any completion rules for `sshpass`. How can I create simple completion rules, so that as soon as I reach the "command" and "arguments", ssh is completed for command and user@host is completed same as it would be for standard ssh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take inspiration from commands with similar syntax, such as [`sudo`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Unix/Command/_sudo) which also takes options followed by a command name and its options. See also [Dynamic zsh autocomplete for custom commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239528/dynamic-zsh-autocomplete-for-custom-commands/240192#240192) for an introduction on writing zsh completions.

Put the following code in a file called `_sshpass` on your `$fpath`. (See [How to properly make custom zsh completions "just work"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535509/how-to-properly-make-custom-zsh-completions-just-work/535646#535646) for more details on how zsh picks up completion functions.)

```
#compdef sshpass

_sshpass () {
  local context state line
  typeset -A opt_args

  _arguments \
    '(-d -e -f -p)-d+[read password from file descriptor]:file descriptor:_file_descriptors' \
    '(-d -e -f -p)-e[take password from $SSHPASS]' \
    '(-d -e -f -p)-f+[read password from file]:file:_files' \
    '(-d -e -f -p)-p+[actual password]::' \
    '(-)1:command:->command' \
    '*::arguments: _normal' \
    && return

  case $state in
    (command)
      if ((CURRENT == 2)); then
        # Insist that the first argument must be an option
        compadd -- -d -e -f -p
      else
        compadd ssh ||
        _command_names -e
      fi
      ;;
  esac
}

_sshpass "$@"
```

Brief explanation:

- [`_arguments`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005farguments) arranges completion for a command with options.
- The options `-d`, `-e`, `-f` and `-p` are mutually exclusive. `(-d -e -f -p)-d…` specifies completions for `-d` and states that this should not be offered if one of the options `-d`, `-e`, `-f` or `-p` is already present.
- `-d+` means that a space is optional between `-d` and its argument.
- `->command` for the first parameter causes `_arguments` to set `$state` to `command` and the execution continues below.
- `_normal` for arguments after the first non-option argument causes them to be completed as if the command line started with the first non-option argument. The `::` after `*` instructs zsh to strip options up the first non-option argument.
- For the command name, try completing the name passed to `compadd` (you can add more names if you want). If this fails, complete any command name instead.

Comment: works great. Thank you.

Comment: why do we define `opt_args`, `context` and `line`> They don't seem to be used. Are they just leftovers form the template we used, or do they have any function here?

Comment: when I do `sshpass <TAB>`, it completes `ssh`. I think, it should first require one of the arguments `-p`, `-e`, `-f`, as `sshpass` does not work otherwise. How do I tell zsh to only complete the command, after one options has been provided?

Comment: @400theCat `opt_args` and the others are necessary to use the `->state` feature of `_arguments`. See the documentation of `_arguments`. I've edited the function to insist that the first argument is an option. It isn't very clean, I'm sure there's a better way, but it does the job here.